# How Can I insert Only Date in the Database C#

Tags: c#, sql

//I have this code and I want to insert only the date in the database without //the time, but this will always store value like this: 2019-10-19 00:00:00.000.

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox_DepartureDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                    DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox_ArrivalDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                    string time1 = TextBox_DepartureTime.Text + " " + DropDownListAMPM.SelectedValue;
                    string time2 = TextBox_ArrivalTime.Text + " " + DropDownList_AMPM2.SelectedValue;

                    DateTime dateOnly1 = date.Date;
                    DateTime dateOnly2 = date2.Date;

                    if (date <= DateTime.Now.Date)
                    {
                        Label_EditTableMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        Label_EditTableMessage.Text = "Departure Date Cannot be in the past";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (date2 <= date)
                        {
                            Label_EditTableMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            Label_EditTableMessage.Text = "Return Date Cannot be Less than the Departure Date";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            cmd2.CommandText = "insert into flight(airline_id,flight_number,numer_seats,departure_city,destination_city,departure_time,arrival_time,departure_date,arrival_date) values( '" + DropDownList_AirlineId.SelectedValue + "','" + TextBox_FlightNumber.Text + "','" + TextBox_NumerSeats.Text + "', '" + TextBox_DepartureCity.Text + "', '" + TextBox_DestinationCity.Text + "', '" + time1 + "', '" + time2 + "', '" + dateOnly1 + "', '" + dateOnly2 + "') ";
                            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Label_EditTableMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                            Label_EditTableMessage.Text = "Flight Added";
                            EmptyTextBoxes();
                            GridView_Flight.DataBind();
                       }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: which datatype is in database?

Comment: it is datetime.

Comment: I think you don't use javascript tag here, it's about .net and c#

Comment: the TextBox_DepartureDate contains the time??

Comment: You shouldn't care about this.  Only the GUI will care when the value gets displayed to the end user, and then, use a format that won't include the time portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your code. You should change the data type of your field in the database. Instead of `datetime` or `datetime2` **you should use** `date`.

You can refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeRelatedTopics

Comment: I changed it but it still store the same thing

Comment: How did you confirm that it's still the same? Inside MSSQL Studio or in your code?

Comment: In the database it will store the date only. But when I try to select this field in Gridview it will show the time along with it.

Comment: @sara if you're assigning to a `DateTime` object it will always append a time to it - it's up to you to write the code so that it is _formatted_ and _displayed_ as date only.

Answer (score 2):

2 parts to this:

1. Your schema probably has the column data type set to `DATETIME` instead of just `DATE` which is going to cause it to store the full date and time regardless. **This is the first thing I would check.**
2. In your C# you can use the `.Date` property on a `DateTime` object to get just the date part of it. **This is irrelevant if you use the correct data type for your column as per point 1**

---

```
date.Date
```

or if you want it in string format:

```
date.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: 3. SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you use

```
DateTime dateOnly1 = date.Date;
DateTime dateOnly2 = date2.Date;
```

and previus you use

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox_DepartureDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox_ArrivalDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

you are working only with date, and the datetime assume the time with 00:00:00

Comment: so how can I fix it?